# RubyOnRails start server runtime error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run RoR server under ubuntu 9.10:

```
>      ruby script/server 
>     => Booting WEBrick
>     => Rails 2.3.4 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
>     /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:271:in
> `require_frameworks': no such file to
> load -- net/https (RuntimeError)
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:134:in
> `process'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:113:in
> `send'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:113:in
> `run'
>       from /home/ockonal/Programming/RoR/demo/demo/config/environment.rb:9
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
> `gem_original_require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
> `require'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in
> `require'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in
> `new_constants_in'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in
> `require'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/commands/server.rb:84
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
> `gem_original_require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
> `require'
>       from script/server:3
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have the Ruby SSL support installed, causing Rails to fail when it looks for `net/https.rb`. If you are using the default Ubuntu Ruby package, then you need to install the `libopenssl-ruby1.8` package.